# Display current URL of webpage (dynamic) in HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, url

I have this code in my HTML:

```
<h3 id="left">Lorem Ipsum </h3>

                <h3 id="right">[Current URL Here]</h3>
```

I want to display (dynamicly) the current URL inside the `<h3>` tags. I've been trying to figure it out for a few days, but I'm really a mobile developer, not an HTML developer, so it's proven difficult. I need this for an app I'm working on, so Please go easy on me :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('right').innerHTML = window.location.href;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to do it in PHP, it's a little more involved:

```
$url = !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$url .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

As [aronasterling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/376728/aaronasterling) points out, you need to sanitize `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to prevent XSS.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you simply cannot do it in pure HTML.

With javascript, you can go with

```
<h3 id="right">
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(location.href);
</script>
</h3>
```

Otherwise, if you are requesting a page on the server, you should rather have it done in there.

Comment: MooGoo's javascript is a cleaner way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

the php code for getting complete url of current page is as follows

```
<?php 

    $protocol = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http';

    echo $protocol.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
```

[Reference](http://www.phpro.org/examples/Get-Full-URL.html)

if you want to use javascript use the method suggested by @MooGoo

full usage of that script is as follows

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">        
   document.getElementById('right').innerHTML = window.location.href;       
</SCRIPT>
```

use this after you declared/defined `<h3 id="right">[Current URL Here]</h3>`

Hope helpful

Comment: -1 for not mentioning to a newb that they should output `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` through `htmlspecialchars`. See here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446459/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-the-super-global-serverphp-self-in-php/3446566#3446566 The same principles apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var segments = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var toDelete = [];
for (var i = 0; i < segments.length; i++) {
    if (segments[i].length < 1) {
        toDelete.push(i);
    }
}
for (var i = 0; i < toDelete.length; i++) {
    segments.splice(i, 1);
}
var filename = segments[segments.length - 1];
console.log(filename);
document.write(filename);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

While the JavaScript are what is more common, you could also use Server-Side Includes:

```
<h3 id="right">
    <!--#echo var="SERVER_NAME" -->/<!--#echo var="DOCUMENT_URI" -->
</h3>
```

- instead of `SERVER_NAME` you can try `HTTP_HOST`
- instead of `DOCUMENT_URI` you can try `REQUEST_URI`; one includes the query string, the other doesn't

Comment: -1 see my comment on every other answer in this thread that involves php.

Comment: @aaronasterling: Read the difference between `DOCUMENT_URI` and `REQUEST_URI`. If asker wanted to avoid XSS, he should use the appropriate one. If asker is on an intranet or using the page for personal use, then XSS is not a threat.

Comment: This is why people should have to submit a resume before given vote capability

Answer (score -1):

Php Code:

```
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}

<h3 id="right">echo curPageURL();</h3>
```